# Is the reciprocal of the modulus of any complex number always less than 1?

Tags: calculus, complex-numbers

[image]

Is the reciprocal of the modulus of any complex number z always <1? I believe that that I could end up with a 0<modulus<1 (thus the reciprocal is > 1). If so, then how did they come up with the expression 1/|z-i| < 1?

Here is also the previous part of the question for some more context:  [image]

Comment: This is hard to follow.  No, the reciprocal of the modulus of a complex number need not be $<1$.  Take $z=\frac 12$ for example.

Comment: If $z \in B$ then we obviously have $|\frac 1 {z-i}|<1$. But in general, no.